# Bulk updating Chrome bookmarks across individual profiles with unique URL's for each profile

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace, bookmarks

I'm trying to find a simple way to update the business bookmarks for a bunch of users, but each user has a different URL for each bookmark, see below table for a better visual description

| User | Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | URL A | URL B | URL C |
| User 2 | URL D | URL E | URL F |
| User 3 | URL G | URL H | URL I |
| User N | URL X | URL Y | URL Z |

Is there anyway that this can be done via any sort of bulk update feature within G Suite Business at all, or is it a matter of changing each one individually as I go along?